# In V8, how are primitive types such as null, undefined, and boolean stored in memory?

Tags: javascript, v8, javascript-engine

Is a `boolean` stored as a 32-bit integer in memory?  How about a `null` value?

In the book [Speaking Javascript](http://speakingjs.com/), 
it refers to a **type tag** being used to indicate the type of a value stored in memory. e.g. The type tag for `Object` type was 000.  What is a type tag?

How would I find the **type tag** of a value type such as a `boolean` or `string`?

Comment: @RichS You may well be right.  You can hit the edit button below the post to suggest an edit. =)

Comment: And for what it's worth, the answer to the question today and in the future will be implementation specific, in which case people would want to Google search "v8" or similar instead of "javascript". Suggested reference: [v8 primitive types](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.12/d0/d4a/classv8_1_1_primitive.html)

Answer (score 3):

From Andy Wingo's [blog post](https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations) on the topic:

> Initially, all JavaScript implementations used tagged pointers to represent JS values. This is a old trick that comes from the observation that allocated memory takes up at least 4 or 8 bytes, and are aligned in such a way that the least significant bit or three will be zero.

So the type tags allow for all values to be stored uniformly. All values occupy one machine word (32/64 bit) and depending on the tag (which is the least significant bit or bits) they are interpreted either as a pointer to an object or as some integer/boolean/etc depending on the tag.

> is boolean stored as a 32-byte integer in js memory?

A boolean also occupies one word. For a more specific answer I'd need to go though the v8 source. But if I remember correctly, `true` and `false` are represented as root pointers.

> how to get the type tag of a value type(boolean,undefined,string, number);

No way to do it from JavaScript. It's internal implementation details.

Comment: oh.good.thanks.but some questions:what is `root pointers`,and in addition, can you find out the` tag type` detail from v8 source?

Comment: @SKing7, sorry for such a delay. _Root objects_ or _root pointers_ is a garbage collection term which means objects live by definition (v8's GC traverses the pointers starting with the roots to define which of them are live and the rest gets GC'd). See http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection. Concerning your second question, why do you need the tag (well, if you still do at all :-) )? Yes, of course information about tags can be found in v8 sources.